# Getting a simple app to work with Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am following the sample from site https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-readme-tab-.  I followed all instructions for Android app in the README.md.  Creates an Android app in Firebase Console, copied google-services.json and update both buidl.gradle files as shown below:

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        // Add this line
        // **********************************
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // **********************************
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.fluttercloudfirestore"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // Add this line
    // **********************************
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    // **********************************
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
// **********************************
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// **********************************
```

**also updated my pubspec.yaml**

```
name: flutter_cloud_firestore
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: "^0.4.0"


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies, 
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

When I run **flutter packages get**, I get the following error:

Running "**flutter packages get**" in flutter_cloud_firestore...
Package cloud_firestore has no versions that match >=0.4.0 <0.5.0 derived from:
- flutter_cloud_firestore depends on version ^0.4.0
pub get failed (1)

According to [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-versions-tab-) page, 0.4.0 is the current version.  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to tell this from the package homepage or the `pub` package manager's error message itself, but it's not available to Flutter's `beta` channel (which is the default as of this post), so you have to switch to the `dev` channel.

You can change the release channel you're on with the `flutter channel` command. In this case, if you're dead set on using `0.4.0` you need to be on the `dev` channel:

```
$ flutter channel dev
$ flutter doctor // May not be strictly necessary, but a good check
```

Then `$ flutter packages get` should fetch the package properly.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to 0.3.2 and it got the packages just fine.  Questions: 1) how do I know form could_firestone page whether the package home page whether the package is on stable/beta or dev channels?  I would like to be able to make this determination myself without having to reach out to StackOverflow.

Comment: No problem. The only thing I was able to find when I looked into it was this diff that bumped the required `flutter` version: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/commit/a76fc24135fa4c47960bc02fdeafdd90489270b0

Theoretically, you could run `$ flutter --version` to figure out which version you're running on and see if it falls within the dependency's `pubspec.yaml`. It kinda sucks.

Comment: Also quick note that I was operating under the assumption that you and I were on the `stable` channel, but there is no such channel, since Flutter is in beta.